# Unable to access HBase shell despite running HMaster

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Hello everyone i have installed HBase on Ubuntu 12.04lts using this link

http://vladexologija.blogspot.in/2011/10/installing-hbase-on-ubuntu.html

But when i start HBase then HMaster is running but the HBase shell is not accessible. JPS shows that HMaster is running with PID 5823. Need some help.

Comment: Could you please show me your HMaster log file?

Comment: Where the logs file is stored.../usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-hduser-master-charnjeet-desktop.log  you need This one

Comment: How i am send this because it have 5000 line in file.??

Comment: You can use http://pastebin.com/ ..copy the logs there and give me the links. Show me last 100 rows.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/YjK5yPqh Link of last so many line of logs file...

Comment: Looks like that zookeeper was down. Check zk logs for exceptions.

Comment: @CharnjeetSingh, did you find any solution to this ?